# Unzip files in alphabetical order

Tags: linux, zip

Is there anyway to unzip to stdout in linux by alphabetical order?  I am unzipping to a fifo file and the files are coming out of order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `unzip` program will be extracting files in the order in which they appear in the archive.  If there are not a large number of files, you could construct a list of files to extract, sort that and run `unzip` in a loop to extract each in the desired order.

Something like (a script of course):

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                  
FILE=$1
unzip -qq -l $1 | awk '{print $4; }' |sort |\
while :
do
    read name
    [ -z "$name" ] && break
    unzip -p $1 "$name"
done
```

The `-qq` option for `unzip` suppresses the header, allowing one to use `awk` to print just the filenames.

Comment: I didn't realize -qq was available.  That makes like easier